# What is the correct way to filter response by query parameter in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, get

If I have a Get request that returns orders of clients, how can I filter the response to give me the objects that have a specific value for example that are made by those specific clients in Spring Boot?
I have tried with @PathVariable and @RequestParams but every attempt failed.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a specific order which has an identifier of some sort, use `@PathVariable`. In the following example, the identifier is a `String`,  but in many case it will rather be long or an Integer.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrdersController {

   @GetMapping("/{id}")
   public Order getOrder(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
      // get the order with a specified id from the backend
   }
}
```

The web request in this case will look like `http:/<host>:<port>/orders/123`

If you want to filter the order by some name, like 'madeBy John', use Request parameter:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrdersController {

   @GetMapping("/")
   public List<Order> getOrdersFilteredByName(@RequestParam("madeBy") madeBy) {
      // get the order filtered by the person who made the order
      // note, this one returns the list
   }
}
```

In this case the web request will look like this: `http:/<host>:<port>/orders?madeBy=John`

Note that technically you can implement whatever you want at the backend, so you can pass, say, `John` in the first example as a path variable, on server its a String after all, however what I've described is a straightforward and kind-of-standard way  of doing these things - so can expect to see this convention in many projects at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

    // http://<host>:<port>/order/1    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Order getOrder(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // Return your order
    }

    // http://<host>:<port>/order?madeBy=John
    @GetMapping("/)
    public List<Order> getOrdersMadeBy(@RequestParam("madeBy") String madeBy) {
        // Return your order list
    }
}
```